# Timeout defined with jcifs does not work

Tags: java, jcifs

I have set responseTimeout and soTimeout to 15000ms but I still get a
timeout after 90000ms.

I tested this on v1.3.18 and v1.3.17.

When I don't register jcifs my default timeout for HttpURLConnection occurs
correctly after 15000ms :

```
connection.setReadTimeout(15000);
connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
```

But when I register jcifs then the timout occurs after 90000ms:

```
System.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.responseTimeout", "15000");
System.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.soTimeout", "15000");
jcifs.Config.registerSmbURLHandler();
[...]
connection.setReadTimeout(15000);
connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
```

It seems that the jcifs timeout and my default timeout are both ignored for
another value.

I have also tried setProperty directly on Config but it does not change :

```
jcifs.Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.responseTimeout", "15000");
jcifs.Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.soTimeout", "15000");
```

Answer (score 3):

(This message was posted to jcifs forum at http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.network.samba.java/9554)

For me the problem is that jcifs wraps a new HttpURLConnection so it loses every settings defined on the original connection, like the timeout settings. To prove this either I use reflection or I modify the library and change jcifs internal connection, then the timeout works fine.

(For information setting jcifs.smb.client.responseTimeout and jcifs.smb.client.soTimeout does not work)

First, I validate that jcifs is the problem : my timeout of 15000ms does not work at all when I use jcifs.Config.registerSmbURLHandler(), connection breaks after 30000ms. My 15000ms timeout works only if I remove the call to registerSmbURLHandler().

Regarding the problem, I open a connection (with jcifs previously registered) :

```
URLConnection myConnection = new URL(url).openConnection();
```

Then the URLStreamHandler creates a wrapping NtlmHttpURLConnection and hides the real HttpURLConnection :

```
protected URLConnection openConnection(URL url) throws IOException {
    url = new URL(url, url.toExternalForm(),
            getDefaultStreamHandler(url.getProtocol()));
    return new NtlmHttpURLConnection((HttpURLConnection)
            url.openConnection());
}
```

So my timeout settings are applied to the wrapper NtlmHttpURLConnection, it's not applied to the true opened URLConnection. So my timeout are useless :

```
myConnection.setReadTimeout(15000);    // applied to the new NtlmHttpURLConnection(wrapped), not the real wrapped one
myConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000); // applied to the new NtlmHttpURLConnection(wrapped), not the real wrapped one
```

There are two solutions I can use to change the timeout on the wrapped connection : with reflection or with a fixed library.

With reflection, I access the private wrapped connection and change the private fields connectTimeout and readTimeout :

```
Class<?> classConnection = myConnection.getClass();

Field privateFieldURLConnection = classConnection.getDeclaredField("connection");
privateFieldURLConnection.setAccessible(true);

URLConnection privateURLConnection = (URLConnection) privateFieldURLConnection.get(myConnection);
Class<?> classURLConnectionPrivate = privateURLConnection.getClass();

Field privateFieldConnectTimeout = classURLConnectionPrivate.getDeclaredField("connectTimeout");
privateFieldConnectTimeout.setAccessible(true);
privateFieldConnectTimeout.setInt(privateURLConnection, 15000);

Field privateFieldReadTimeout = classURLConnectionPrivate.getDeclaredField("readTimeout");
privateFieldReadTimeout.setAccessible(true);
privateFieldReadTimeout.setInt(privateURLConnection, 15000);
```

Or I modify the jcifs library and the constructor NtlmHttpURLConnection() :

```
public NtlmHttpURLConnection(HttpURLConnection connection) {
    super(connection.getURL());
    this.connection = connection;

    this.connection.setReadTimeout(15000);
    this.connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);

    requestProperties = new HashMap();
}
```