# jdk http client ntlm

Tags: java, httpclient, java-http-client

I am not by far an expert in different protocols over http, but I can do this with curl to one of the APIs at my workplace:

```
curl  --http1.1 --ntlm -u 'user:pass' 'MY_URL'
```

This works just fine. But notice that I can specify `--ntlm`.

I am trying to replicate the same thing with `http-jdk-client`, so something like this:

```
var client = HttpClient.newBuilder()
            .authenticator(new Authenticator() {
                @Override
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(<user>, <pass>.toCharArray());
                }
            })
            .sslContext(sslContext()) // an SSL Context that trusts everyone
            .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1)
            .build();
    var request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(URI.create(url))
            .build();
    client.sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString())
            .thenApply(HttpResponse::body)
            .thenAccept(System.out::println)
            .join();
```

This fails with a `401`.

On the other hand if I use the same `curl`, *but* drop the `--ntlm`, I get the same `401`. So it really seems to me I need to somehow replicate that flag in the jdk client.

Someone knows some hints or ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you should mention what `--ntlm` does.

Comment: @BasilBourque I am still reading myself what that does and how, so...

Comment: The client has to support NTLM. If you’re not limited to the JDK client, [here is a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67182496/839733) using Apache HTTP client.

Comment: Also, finding out what NTLM does is a matter of simple Google search. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/microsoft-ntlm

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar when I said "reading", it meant I was documenting myself enough. And no, a different client is not really an option. Thx, though.

Comment: This article outlines how to provide an NTLM authenticator: https://despinapapatheodorou.medium.com/httpclient-with-ntlm-authentication-be6a995b7575

Comment: @AllenD.Ball that refers to the apache http client.

Comment: The article outlines the HTTP communications you'll need to implement to authenticate.

The client sends the user name to the server (format DomainName\Username) (Username)
The server generates a 16-byte random number, called a Challenge or Nonce, and sends it to the client. (Challenge)
The client encrypts this challenge with the hash of the user’s password and returns the result to the server. (Response)
The server sends to the DC the Username,Challenge,Response
The DC validates if the authentication is successful.

You can use the Apache HTTP client source for a reference.

Comment: @AllenD.Ball it is by far not as easy after I [read this](http://davenport.sourceforge.net/ntlm.html)

Comment: I wasn't suggesting it was easy; But, if the Apache HTTP client or some other 3rd-party solution are not options, that's the work you'll need to do.

Comment: @AllenD.Ball indeed, I was not trying to be defensive in no manner, btw. Your input was valuable, thank you. I will end up introducing a library for this call and will slowly work into an integration with http jdk client.

Comment: No worries -- Good luck!

Comment: java.net.http.HttpClient doesn't support NTLM authentication.

Comment: thank you @Daniel, this puts this question to rest, for sure.

Comment: You could try to implement NTLM on top of HttpClient by handling 401 errors manually, but NTLM also typically implies controlling the underlying TCP connection, which the `java.net.HttpClient` doesn't let you do. Though you *might* make it work - due to the fact that the connections are pooled & reused. That said NTLM over HTTP is not safe. The legacy `HttpURLConnection` still supports NTLM.