# NTLM authentication was deprecated in HttpClient 5.3.1; can I authenticate using headers? (Java)

Tags: java, ntlm, apache-commons-httpclient

[deprecation notice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzG3s.png). My workplace still uses the NTLM authentication scheme. We have over 600k employees so it's not a small company. If I encounter the 401 status code, "NTLM" is the only scheme that is accepted. How can I utilize the newer versions of Apache HttpClient and still handle the NTLM challenge-response? Is it possible to use an existing Java library and work directly with the headers?

I've searched stack overflow for NTLM and HttpClient deprecation but can't find anything helpful.

Comment: Check my answer where I implemented NTLM with spring-web and org.apache.httpcomponents - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020734/using-ntlm-authentication-in-java-applications/67182496#67182496

Answer (score 1):

> How can I utilize the newer versions of Apache HttpClient and still handle the NTLM challenge-response?

According to the latest published javadocs for Apache HttpClient 5.4 alpha, NTLM support has not been removed yet.  However, that won't be a long term solution.

The real problem here is that Microsoft is planning to kill off NTLM ... because it is no longer considered to be secure:

- https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/microsoft-plans-to-kill-off-ntlm-authentication-in-windows-11/
- https://specopssoft.com/blog/microsoft-phases-out-ntlm-with-kerberos/

So, sooner or later your company is going to have to switch from NTLM to something better.

I guess you could investigate other Java HTTP client libraries to see if they intend to keep NTLM support going longer.  But it strikes me as a waste of effort to convert all of your code ... as a solution to the NTLM problem.  Likewise, creating and maintaining your own fork of the Apache HTTPClient library (where NTLM support continues) would be an effort sink ... assuming that you / your team had the skills to do it.

---

> Is it possible to use an existing Java library and work directly with the headers?

I can't see how you would do that.  And assuming it is actually feasible, it would be a bad idea to roll your own NTLM implementation  even if you are security expert.

---

In short, I don't think there are any easy solutions.

Answer (score 0):

My IT infrastructure told me a few weeks ago that NTLM would soon no longer be supported as well, so I had the same concern as you recently about creating an app with SSO in a full Windows environment (Apache servers, PHP code, Edge/FF/Chrome browsers).

Although I'm still convinced that NTLM will remain in place for years, I've been looking for alternatives.

Perhaps you could try **KERBEROS**, depending on your environment.
It could work in a similar way.

What is your working environment? I suppose a mix of Linux servers/Windows clients?

In my case, I ended up going for an **ADFS** server queried via **OIDC** (OpenId Connect) and **OAuth2**. **SAML** was also available if wanted to use it.

Does your infrastructure have an AD/LDAP server? If so, you could set up an ADFS server "quite simply". When you tell me that you manage 600k customers, I however can imagine nothing is simple.